# How to do this Nginx location configuration

Tags: nginx

I currently have

```
        location /folder1 {
            configuration goes here
        }    

        location /folder2 {
            configuration goes here
        }
```

I want to serve .mp4 files in these two locations by using the mp4 module

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
  mp4;
}
```

What is the proper way to do this? If I just add `location ~ \.mp4$` like above, then wouldn't mp4 files lose configuration from the location folder its in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /folder1 {
    folder1 config;
}    
location ~* ^/folder1/.*\.mp4$ {
    folder1 config duplicated;
    mp4;
}

location /folder2 {
    folder2 config;
}
location ~* ^/folder2/.*\.mp4$ {
    folder2 config duplicated;
    mp4;
}
```

nginx doesn't try to combine all of the config sections like Apache does, in order to achieve speed and simplicity.  The drawback to that is that you'll need to duplicate your folder directives in the location blocks for the mp4 files.

Answer (score 3):

Use nested locations:

```
location /folder1 {

       ...

       location ~ \.mp4$ {
             mp4;
       }
}
```

Comment: The nginx documentation said nested locations might not be a good idea

Comment: http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2011-February/025204.html fits the case

Comment: The result is the same as Shane Madden's answer right?

Comment: Yes, result will be the same, but that configuration will affect the performance. A little bit :)