# configure nginx with multiple locations

Tags: nginx

I have `nginx` configuration like this:

```
location = / {
    [ configuration A ]
}

location /documents/ {
    [ configuration B ]
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    [ configuration C ]
}
```

If I request:
`http://www.domain.com/documents/some.gif`
it is `configuration C`.

What to change, so this to be catch from `configuration B` ?

Comment: Pos duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/336742/how-to-do-this-nginx-location-configuration?rq=1

Comment: no is not same.

Comment: I beg to differ, the link question was basically. I wish to serve a file type from multiple locations, but I have two locations that match the condition. Your solution and the one presented there would have resulted in the same result

Comment: then probably the other person asked unclear. 

the way I understand he (administrator) want nginx to serve mp4 files from different locations. 

In my case I want *.jpg to be served with "configuration C", but I wish /documents/*.jpg to be served with "configuration B".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `^~` prior `/documents/` location. This ensure the proper processing.

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then
>   regular expressions are not checked.

Here is the conf file:

```
location = / {
    [ configuration A ]
}

location ^~ /documents/ {
    [ configuration B ]
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    [ configuration C ]
}
```